# discord.py send_message usage

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've started working on a project to accelerate my learning of python. I'm trying to recreate a discord bot I use quite a bit since i'm already use to its features. Below is my current code

```
import discord
from discord import User
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

import secrets

pybot = Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@pybot.event
async def on_read():
    print("Client logged in")

@pybot.command()
async def hello(*args):
    print(User.display_name)
    return await pybot.say("Hello, world!")

@pybot.command()
async def truck(*args):
    await pybot.send_message(message.user,'Watchout for that truck!')

pybot.run(secrets.BOT_TOKEN)
```

what im trying to get to happen is when someone types the command `!truck <mention user>` it sends a message to that mentioned user with the message "Watch out for that truck!".

I'm getting the following error:

> Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

I've tried looking up examples of what im trying to do but haven't found much, or am not understanding what I should be doing. Hopefully this isn't a repost of a similar question

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *args in your truck is no longer valid syntax I believe for the commands with discord.py

```
@pybot.command(pass_context=True)
async def truck(ctx):
    await pybot.send_message(ctx.message.user, 'Watchout for that truck!')
```

Checkout the github repository for Discord.py with their [examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/async/examples)

Comment: thank you! I see that now. I was following a blog post that seems to be outdated. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Yeah I recommend you check out the discord api server in discord, it's got a lot of helpful people as well as the guy who coded the discord.py