# How to dm person who used command in discord

Tags: python, discord

This is my code to dm the person doing the command:

```
 @client.command()
 async def test(pass_context=True):
     await message.author.sendMessage("test")
```

what my code is supposed to do is when someone does (this is an example) !test then they would receive a Direct Message saying something. When I try this it tells me: NameError: name 'message' is not defined. And I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What does it do? What is your expected result vs the actual result? Do you get any errors? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for not being detailed, what my code is supposed to do is when someone does (this is an example) !test then they would receive a Direct Message saying something. When I try this it tells me: NameError: name 'message' is not defined. And I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: Perhaps try searching for your error code? Possible duplicate of [discord.py send\_message ussage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970789/discord-py-send-message-ussage)

Comment: Tried, may have worked, but now name 'send_message' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @client.command(pass_context=True)
 async def test(ctx):
     await client.send_message(ctx.message.author, "test")
```

You're passing context, you can use that context to send directly to the author of the message.

You're also using `pass_context=True` in the wrong place, it needs to be where you're *creating* the command, not *defining* it.

(i.e `ctx.message.author`, `ctx.message.channel`)